# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cocos2d-x

I'm new to cocos2d-x platform and tried to run the tests on Linux(Ubuntu 13.04) environment.
I have followed the steps from [git-cocos2d-x](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x) and got the following error while executing 
`cocos run -p linux` command.

> **/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglfw
>     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status**

Can anybody tell me how to fix this error ?

Any help would be appreciable.

After installation I got the following errors

> lib/libcocos2d.a(CCGLView.cpp.o): In function `cocos2d::GLView::GLView()':
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:275: undefined reference to`glfwSetErrorCallback'
>   lib/libcocos2d.a(CCGLView.cpp.o): In function `cocos2d::GLView::initWithRect(std::string const&, cocos2d::Rect, float)':
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:337: undefined reference to`glfwWindowHint'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:343: undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:344: undefined reference to`glfwMakeContextCurrent'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:347: undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorPosCallback'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:348: undefined reference to`glfwSetScrollCallback'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:351: undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowPosCallback'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:352: undefined reference to`glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback'
>   lib/libcocos2d.a(CCGLView.cpp.o): In function `cocos2d::GLView::initWithFullScreen(std::string const&)':
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:381: undefined reference to`glfwGetPrimaryMonitor'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:385: undefined reference to `glfwGetVideoMode'
>   lib/libcocos2d.a(CCGLView.cpp.o): In function`cocos2d::GLView::initWithFullscreen(std::string const&, GLFWvidmode const&, GLFWmonitor*)':
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:397: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:398: undefined reference to`glfwWindowHint'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:399: undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:400: undefined reference to`glfwWindowHint'
>   lib/libcocos2d.a(CCGLView.cpp.o): In function `cocos2d::GLView::end()':
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:414: undefined reference to`glfwSetWindowShouldClose'
>   lib/libcocos2d.a(CCGLView.cpp.o): In function `cocos2d::GLView::windowShouldClose()':
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:430: undefined reference to`glfwWindowShouldClose'
>   lib/libcocos2d.a(CCGLView.cpp.o): In function `cocos2d::GLView::updateFrameSize()':
>   cocos2d-x/NTT-Game/MyGame/cocos2d/cocos/platform/desktop/CCGLView.cpp:489: undefined reference to`glfwGetFramebufferSize'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have libglfw installed on system? Since version 3 of that library the link flag is `-lglfw3`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. Now I have installed libglfw and getting some new errors as mentioned above.

Comment: CCGLView.h includes "glfw3.h" but compiler doesn't find it; it looks in `/usr/include`, `/usr/include/GLFW` and `/usr/local/include/GLFW` but I think is placed elsewhere, does the source has a configure script to search for glfw and set the correct compile flags? (it's `-I/usr/include/<glfw3.h folder>`)

Comment: wait, you said Ubuntu, did you installed -devel package?

Comment: Yes. I have installed it

Comment: For some odd reason the linker can't find `-lglfw3` but can find `-lglfw` for me, (whenever I install either `libglfw3-dev` or `libglfw-dev`, it removes the other one if it is installed) so I have to use either way the `-lglfw` flag.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I tried to build a Cocos2d-x project on OpenSuSE.  Go to the root directory of your Cocos2d-x project and from there change to the 'cocos2d/cocos' directory.  Open up the CMakeLists.txt file and look for the list of PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_LIBS for Linux. You should see a section that looks similar to this:

```
if(LINUX)
set(PLATFORM_SPECIFIC_LIBS
    pthread
    fontconfig
    GLEW
    X11
    rt
    glfw3
    Xi
    Xrandr
    Xxf86vm
    GL
    ${FMOD_LIB}
    )
```

In my file I had to change 'glfw' to 'glfw3' and add dependencies on Xi, Xrandr, and Xxf86vm to get the program to build.